# How to move tasks thus sprint is not always 100% completed

Tags: analytics, sprint, burndowncharts

we use azuredevops in our team and try to understand our efficency by using analytics, especially sprint burndown.

When we come to the end of our sprint, we move tasks that are not completed in next sprint. Now, burndown chart show always 100% because tasks are in the next sprint- which I could understand.

But how is it possible to see the real %? How and when do we have to move tasks, thus it is not always 100% cause we dont finish all tasks every sprint.

I couldnt imagine that we have to copy tasks, so that the right % of completed work is shown.

Thanks for help. Best Laura

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you probably want [pm.se].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.